# Gentoo installation issues

Tags: linux, gentoo

I have decided to take the next step in learning linux and have taken on GENTOO. I am following the tutorial on this site

http://negativesum.net/tech/linux/gentoo/install_guide

I am currently at 11 "Get the stage 3 tarball (assuming you're doing a stage 3 install, which we are)" and I am trying to connect to links2.

but I am totally new to trying to connect to a wifi on gentoo.

I have looked at many forums and blogs and have come across WPA_SUPPLICANT. my wireless provider is UPC (located in Ireland) so it is WPA/WPA2.

I have tried to follow many tutorials for example

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=4&chap=4

but when I try to follow them (one tutorial said to use the command )

```
$ emerge wpa_supplicant
```

in order to install it, it was not recognised as a command. (one example of many issues)

I have also tried to find the driver but cannot find out which one it is, I'm installing it on a Sony Vaio W12s1e netbook with an intel atom processor and 1gb RAM

I have been at this for awhile and just need to set up my wifi in Gentoo

If you can tell me how it would really help me

Comment: Shell commands are case-sensitive and it should be `emerge wpa_supplicant`. Also, don't follow some random website, but the official Gentoo installation guides from http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/?catid=install#doc_chap2.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, yes I put them in the way they were suppose to put them in. I was just emphasising the code part. I was looking at that site too, I am just really really confused on how to set up my wireless, WPA and wpa_supplicant

Comment: The gentoo link you posted states that you should run `emerge net-wireless/wpa_supplicant`. Have you tried his? Also, please include the error messages you are getting.

Comment: Hi yes I did and it stated that "emerge: command not found"

Comment: I would use a different Linux distro other than Gentoo.  Gentoo is overly complicated... and overly complicated does not equate to a better understanding of Linux.

Comment: I know, but now that I have started, I have to finish it and figure it out ha ha. Never quit, you'll get there eventually :)

Comment: emerge is part of the portage package, and if you don't have that installed your installation is truely broken (portage is at the heart of Gentoo). This is impossible to fix without going into the gory details on how you came to that point of a broken Gentoo installation.

Comment: I downloaded the minimal package and burned it to a cd and literally followed the tutorial from start to when I got stuck (the link I gave up above)

http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/x86/autobuilds/current-iso/

On this website I downloaded the iso 

install-x86-minimal-20121213.iso

Comment: Did you check that the firmware is loaded?  Does `iwconfig` show any wireless resources?  If yes, did you `net-setup` (I think?) to set-up the wireless?

Comment: yes I tried net-setup but it wouldnt work

it had wlan0 and lo so I'm guessing it showed wireless networks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got far enough through the installation to use emerge yet. The "chroot" step enters you into your new installation where you can install additional packages. The point of getting net access in the beginning is so that you can download a Portage tree snapshot but you could get hold of this some other way like downloading it onto a USB stick on another system. Generally speaking, I would steer clear of wireless until you're up and running because configuring it from the command line isn't much fun. Once you have a desktop, you can use graphical tools like wpa_gui.

And do please ignore the guy above. Gentoo was my second distro back in 2002 and I probably knew about as much as you did. I'm still using it to this day and my Linux knowledge is now a very big part of my day job. I have Gentoo to thank for that.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice. I will start again from beginning and use a wired connection. I understand it is very hard but I feel if you never quit you will accomplish anything eventually :) 

Thank you

Comment: Alternatively, use one of the LiveDVDs, to have working wifi while installing.